# custom 404 Error page for backend site in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I want to create custom 404 page for prefix backend. but it is only show front site 404 error page.. when backend/404-url i want to get with backend. layout 404..

```
Route::prefix('/backend')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/test','BackController@index');
    Route::get('/home','BackController@home');
    Route::resources([
    'categories' => 'CategoryController',
    'posts' => 'PostController',
    'users'=>'UserController'
]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add/modify the render method in app/Exceptions/Handler.php to return a json response for an ajax request or a view for a normal request if the exception is one of ModelNotFoundException or NotFoundHttpException.

so your code will be look like this:

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e) {

    $status = $e->getStatusCode();

    if(Request::is('/backend/*')) { //Chane to your backend your !
        return response()->view("backend/errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
    }else {
        return response()->view("errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
    }

}
```

some links to help you achieve this:

[Laravel Documentation on errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors)

[Scoth.io tutorial for creating a 404 page using custom exception handler](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-laravel-404-page-using-custom-exception-handlers)